# SMPS Transformer Primary Winding Ringing

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback, snubber

We are working on a 24V 4A flyback SMPS design. But when we analyze the primary winding of SMPS transformer, we are determining very high voltage oscillations(ringing) up to 350V. But our DC bus is 150V. We have snubber circuit for primary side. ( f(switching)=100kHz )

[image: SMPS Primary Side Ring]

[image: SMPS]

When we analyze another 24V 4A SMPS from market and when we remove the snubber circuit of this SMPS, their SMPS primary winding oscillations is 10 % of our primary side oscillations of SMPS that is designed by us.

Why we are getting too much oscillation/ringing voltage?

Comment: Compare the two turn ratios. Maybe yours has a higher turns ratio and maybe your transformer has more leakage inductance. Can you explain how many volts/cm your oscilloscope was using. 150 volts doesn't appear to fit very well onto your screen scale.

Comment: Try to read this: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf (page 33 and 34)

Comment: What’s your leakage inductance of the transformer?

Comment: Check the gate voltage if possible, so that you don't have any on/off ringing there

Comment: High leakage inductance and no damping in the primary clamp circuit.